# Sum multiple reports

Tags: mysql

I have a query...

```
SELECT `fac` SUM(`a`),SUM(`b`),SUM(`c`),SUM(`d`)   
FROM `x` WHERE `dateTime` BETWEEN '2016-06-13 'AND '2016-06-14' AND `fac` = 1
```

...that outputs this:

```
|fac|sumA|sumB|sumC|sumD|  
+---+----+----+----+----+  
|  1|x   |    |    |    |
```

But I'm trying to loop the query to output `fac` five times:

```
|fac|sumA|sumB|sumC|sumD|  
+---+----+----+----+----+  
|  1|x   |    |    |    |  
+---+----+----+----+----+  
|  2|x   |    |    |    |  
+---+----+----+----+----+  
|  3|x   |    |    |    |  
+---+----+----+----+----+  
|  4|x   |    |    |    |  
+---+----+----+----+----+  
|  5|x   |    |    |    |
```

Comment: `But im trying to do loop the query to output 5 fac` -- What exactly do you mean?  Searching for multiple `fac` records or duplicating the same record multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `fac`
     , SUM(`a`)
     , SUM(`b`)
     , SUM(`c`)
     , SUM(`d`)   
  FROM `x`
 WHERE `dateTime` BETWEEN '2016-06-13' AND '2016-06-14'
   AND `fac` IN (1,2,3,4,5)
 GROUP BY `fac`
 ORDER BY `fac`
```

If there are no rows for a given `fac` that satisfy the condition on `dateTime`, then there won't be a row for that `fac`. That is, you aren't guaranteed that this query will return five rows; just like your original query isn't guaranteed to return a row.

For the BETWEEN range on `dateTime`, that's going to include rows for midnight of `2016-06-14`.

Those same rows will be included if you do `BETWEEN '2016-06-14' AND ...`

With datetime ranges, to get the rows from one day, we typically do a >= and a < range.

```
WHERE `datetime` >= '2016-06-13'
  AND `datetime` <  '2016-06-14'
```

If you want to always return five rows, with zeros when there aren't any rows for that `fac`, you need a guaranteed row source for the five `fac` values.  Something like this:

```
SELECT i.`fac`
     , IFNULL(SUM(t.`a`),0)
     , IFNULL(SUM(t.`b`),0)
     , IFNULL(SUM(t.`c`),0)
     , IFNULL(SUM(t.`d`),0)   
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS `fac`
         UNION ALL SELECT 2
         UNION ALL SELECT 3
         UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 5
       ) i
  LEFT
  JOIN `x` t
    ON t.`fac` = i.`fac`
   AND t.`dateTime` >= '2016-06-13' 
   AND t.`dateTime` <  '2016-06-14'
   AND t.`fac` IN (1,2,3,4,5)
 GROUP BY i.`fac`
 ORDER BY i.`fac`
```

Answer (score 0):

try to loop the query to output 4 instead.

Hope this helps out, vote up!

Comment: Im trying to avoid a server-side fix. I would like to keep it all in the query.

Comment: You simply need group by and to remove the condition on fac in the select:
'
SELECT `fac`, SUM(`a`), SUM(`b`), SUM(`c`), SUM(`d`)   
FROM `x
WHERE `dateTime` BETWEEN '2016-06-13 'AND '2016-06-14' 
GROUP BY fac;
'
In most databases, your original query would return an error because fac is in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY, and not an argument to an aggregation function.

If you want to limit the results only to those 5 facs, then you can add and fac in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need `group by` and to remove the condition on `fac` in the `select`:

```
SELECT `fac`, SUM(`a`), SUM(`b`), SUM(`c`), SUM(`d`)   
FROM `x
WHERE `dateTime` BETWEEN '2016-06-13 'AND '2016-06-14' 
GROUP BY fac;
```

In most databases, your original query would return an error because `fac` is in the `SELECT` clause but not in the `GROUP BY`, and not an argument to an aggregation function.

If you want to limit the results only to those 5 facs, then you can add `and fac in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` to the `where` clause.